# Change the Visible property on several elements at once

Tags: c#, .net, boolean, visible

In this code I have several elements like text box and buttons, and on depend the case, some are visible and some are not, like this (there are more elements):

```
txtTipCOP.Visible = true;
lblIngreseCantidad.Visible = true;
lblEquivale.Visible = true;
txtTCDolar.Visible = false;
txtTCEuro.Visible = false;
btnCantidadInicio.Visible = false;
btnEquivaleInicio.Visible = false;
txtCantidad.Visible = false;
txtEquivalen.Visible = false;
```

I want to optimize the code, but I don't know how to control several `Visible` properties with 1 true, is this possible?

Thank you for your time.

I am changing every `Visible` property individually but I think it's not the optimal way?

Comment: Somewhere in your code you have to specify which controls are to be visible and which ones are to be hidden. While we could find some "clever" way to put your controls into some sort of collection and iterate over it, the way you have it written is probably best. It's commonly done this way and is very unambiguous.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. Yes, I think although the way I am writing the properties ( one at once, everyone) might no be short but it seems to be the "most" efficent way. So I think I am going to leave the code as it. Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to set all these controls to Visible = true, you could create a foreach loop. Modify the following to your needs.

```
foreach (Control control in Page.Controls)
{
        if (control is TextBox || control is Label) // whatever controls you want
        {
            control.Visible = false;
        }
}
```

However in terms of performance, it will be negligible because its performing the same operation if you set them all individually. Personally I would go with ever is more maintainable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But I think although the way I am writing the properties ( one at once, everyone) might no be short but it seems to be the "most" efficent way. So I think I am going to leave the code as it. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: There are many ways to do the same thing. Readability and maintainability should always be considered. Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

Trivially you could do this:

```
txtTipCOP.Visible = 
lblIngreseCantidad.Visible =
lblEquivale.Visible = true;
        
txtTCDolar.Visible = 
txtTCEuro.Visible =
btnCantidadInicio.Visible =
btnEquivaleInicio.Visible =
txtCantidad.Visible = 
txtEquivalen.Visible = false;
```

A better approach might be this:

```
Control[] controls = new Control[]
{
    txtTipCOP,
    lblIngreseCantidad,
    lblEquivale,
    txtTCDolar,
    txtTCEuro,
    btnCantidadInicio,
    btnEquivaleInicio,
    txtCantidad,
    txtEquivalen,
};

controls.Take(3).ForEach(c => c.Visible = true);
controls.Skip(3).ForEach(c => c.Visible = false);
```

Or:

```
foreach (Control control in controls.Take(3))
    control.Visible = true;

foreach (Control control in controls.Skip(3))
    control.Visible = false;
```

If you don't have the `.ForEach` extension method you can use `.ToList().ForEach` instead.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. But I think although the way I am writing the properties ( one at once, everyone) might no be short but it seems to be the "most" efficent way. So I think I am going to leave the code as it. Thank you again for your time.